# Unable to resolve the source file for

Tags: magento2, javascript

When I run it, the system log shows the message Unable to resolve the source file for, but when I check the path of the js files, Magento runs at the wrong path. Does anyone know how to fix this error?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands from CLI and then check.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: i tried your way but it did'nt work